# Shapely unable to tell if polygon contains point

Tags: python, point-in-polygon, shapely

For an application I want to determine under which constituency a given coordinate falls. After looking at the various options, I decided upon shapely and fiona as the easiest way to implement this. Here is what I wrote for testing if a given coordinate is within a given constituency.

```
import fiona 
import shapely.geometry

fc = fiona.open("shapefile.shp")
shapefile_record = fc.next()
shape = shapely.geometry.asShape(shapefile_record['geometry'])
def is_constituency(lat,lng):
    point = shapely.geometry.Point(lat,lng)
    print shape.contains(point)
```

This yields false for all tests, even when I am sure the coordinate falls within said constituency.

To give an example, the first record

```
>>> shapefile_record['properties']
OrderedDict([(u'DIST_NAME', u'Uttarkashi'), (u'Assem_No', 2), (u'AREA', 0.003), (u'PERIMETER', 0.381), (u'INDIAASSEM', 2802.0), (u'INDIAASS', 0.0), (u'NO', 0.0), (u'ST_CODE', u'S28'), (u'AC_NAME', u'GANGOTRI'), (u'AC_TYPE', u'GEN'), (u'PC_NO', 0.0), (u'AC_NO', 2.0), (u'AC_HNAME', u'\x90\xd6\xd3\x90\xd6\xd6\xea\xa1\xd6\xdf'), (u'PARTY', u'INC'), (u'CODE_NO', u'S282'), (u'Longitude', 78.8900584624), (u'Latitude', 30.9787742252), (u'State', u'Uttaranchal'), (u'PC_NAME', u'Tehri Garhwal'), (u'PC_TYPE', u'GEN'), (u'PC_CODE', u'S2801'), (u'PC_NO_1', 1)])
```

Choosing the point right at the center of the constituency as described in the shapefile gives me false

```
>>>is_constituency(30.9787, 78.8900)
False
```

To make it even clearer that this is wrong, consider this:

```
>>> shape.contains(shapely.geometry.Point(shapefile_record['properties']['Latitude'],shapefile_record['properties']['Longitude']))
False
```

This means that latitude and longitude that define a polygon in its shapefile are not in the polygon?

What am I doing wrong? The whole geometry of this particular record is here:

```
>>> shapefile_record['geometry']
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(78.38236181915738, 31.26909614048731), (78.37916181915745, 31.268796140487385), (78.3822618191574, 31.267896140487327), (78.3863618191574, 31.25889614048731), (78.38236181915738, 31.26909614048731), (78.39066181915734, 31.27209614048735), (78.39166181915749, 31.26569614048737), (78.39476181915734, 31.261196140487364), (78.40206181915738, 31.253896140487317), (78.40136181915733, 31.247396140487414), (78.40616181915749, 31.242696140487347), (78.40616181915749, 31.23999614048722), (78.42386181915737, 31.242196140487348), (78.42906181915743, 31.251396140487262), (78.43636181915747, 31.24869614048731), (78.43946181915743, 31.241396140487275), (78.45286181915736, 31.236896140487264), (78.46626181915747, 31.219596140487393), (78.47446181915734, 31.213196140487415), (78.47546181915749, 31.203196140487254), (78.47896181915735, 31.201496140487286), (78.47846181915736, 31.194996140487323), (78.47896181915735, 31.19249614048727), (78.48206181915737, 31.184496140487397), (78.47876181915751, 31.19379614048734), (78.4857618191574, 31.196796140487265), (78.52196181915735, 31.195196140487383), (78.54586181915738, 31.198096140487337), (78.55736181915728, 31.210896140487364), (78.5636618191574, 31.219196140487334), (78.5688618191574, 31.22109614048736), (78.57406181915741, 31.225696140487283), (78.58656181915745, 31.227596140487265), (78.59066181915745, 31.226696140487267), (78.59438800139878, 31.2276993433984), (78.59466544240831, 31.215214497963416), (78.59476181915738, 31.21519614048731), (78.59136181915744, 31.17679614048729), (78.59196181915752, 31.172796140487268), (78.59266181915734, 31.164396140487323), (78.59336181915734, 31.16029614048739), (78.59396181915747, 31.155696140487294), (78.59476181915738, 31.15239614048727), (78.59456181915738, 31.14619614048729), (78.59436181915748, 31.141196140487295), (78.5928618191574, 31.133996140487348), (78.5905618191573, 31.12569614048732), (78.58506181915737, 31.11289614048735), (78.5836618191575, 31.10639614048739), (78.58076181915737, 31.096596140487296), (78.58046181915745, 31.09129614048732), (78.57956181915739, 31.08559614048733), (78.57696181915736, 31.076796140487325), (78.57396181915749, 31.071496140487405), (78.56966181915732, 31.06689614048731), (78.56486181915739, 31.060396140487345), (78.56036181915738, 31.055896140487338), (78.55746181915742, 31.052096140487386), (78.55496181915748, 31.046596140487395), (78.5543618191574, 31.041796140487406), (78.5548618191574, 31.038396140487293), (78.55676181915737, 31.034696140487252), (78.55856181915749, 31.0320961404874), (78.56126181915738, 31.02909614048736), (78.56596181915745, 31.02629614048732), (78.5732618191575, 31.023096140487386), (78.57816181915734, 31.02039614048727), (78.58316181915734, 31.016896140487408), (78.58716181915736, 31.012596140487236), (78.58916181915748, 31.00639614048726), (78.58886181915733, 31.001996140487396), (78.58746181915751, 30.995996140487247), (78.58346181915749, 30.986896140487318), (78.57896181915748, 30.980196140487354), (78.57056181915738, 30.972696140487248), (78.56596181915745, 30.96759614048733), (78.56176181915737, 30.968296140487386), (78.55476181915748, 30.971496140487265), (78.5496618191574, 30.974296140487304), (78.54546181915731, 30.976396140487346), (78.53686181915737, 30.98029614048727), (78.52476181915739, 30.983996140487363), (78.51606181915747, 30.986996140487406), (78.50816181915735, 30.990596140487355), (78.50236181915744, 30.992896140487236), (78.49326181915751, 30.995196140487277), (78.48246181915738, 30.999296140487274), (78.47446181915734, 31.0025961404873), (78.46366181915744, 31.005896140487263), (78.45626181915748, 31.007296140487316), (78.44656181915747, 31.007196140487395), (78.4316618191574, 31.004596140487365), (78.41926181915744, 31.001396140487266), (78.4112618191574, 30.99869614048737), (78.38606181915742, 30.98579614048726), (78.37846181915745, 30.981396140487337), (78.37416181915745, 30.9783961404873), (78.36956181915735, 30.973696140487395), (78.36226181915748, 30.9683961404873), (78.35336181915739, 30.962196140487322), (78.34116181915743, 30.953296140487396), (78.33196181915741, 30.947096140487254), (78.32336181915747, 30.94129614048734), (78.31436181915745, 30.93129614048735), (78.30736181915734, 30.92489614048736), (78.30266181915749, 30.92099614048726), (78.30016181915744, 30.919296140487294), (78.30116181915736, 30.91489614048737), (78.3021618191575, 30.90809614048732), (78.30356181915738, 30.901896140487345), (78.30516181915738, 30.89799614048741), (78.30666181915751, 30.89399614048739), (78.30926181915737, 30.89179614048726), (78.3134618191574, 30.888796140487333), (78.3177618191574, 30.887196140487337), (78.3229618191574, 30.88539614048722), (78.33026181915744, 30.884896140487236), (78.33486181915737, 30.88459614048731), (78.33986181915736, 30.884696140487396), (78.34626181915735, 30.88499614048738), (78.35076181915736, 30.88479614048731), (78.35426181915744, 30.88459614048731), (78.35746181915732, 30.881596140487257), (78.35656181915749, 30.87819614048732), (78.3564618191574, 30.872696140487342), (78.35476181915743, 30.86789614048735), (78.35346181915747, 30.864896140487307), (78.34546181915744, 30.864996140487396), (78.33756181915749, 30.864596140487325), (78.33196181915741, 30.86419614048731), (78.32406181915746, 30.863896140487327), (78.31806181915732, 30.86529614048738), (78.3147618191573, 30.865196140487235), (78.30956181915747, 30.864696140487297), (78.3039618191574, 30.86399614048725), (78.30076181915751, 30.863496140487253), (78.2982618191574, 30.861796140487286), (78.29416181915747, 30.859296140487405), (78.29186181915742, 30.85379614048725), (78.28946181915745, 30.848196140487346), (78.2874618191575, 30.84429614048725), (78.28206181915743, 30.842096140487282), (78.27806181915741, 30.838696140487343), (78.27956181915738, 30.83389614048741), (78.28066181915744, 30.829396140487404), (78.28196181915735, 30.825696140487317), (78.28436181915731, 30.819196140487414), (78.28906181915738, 30.80999614048733), (78.28686181915742, 30.80739614048736), (78.27936181915737, 30.803196140487277), (78.27506181915737, 30.800396140487237), (78.2684618191575, 30.797696140487343), (78.26506181915738, 30.795996140487375), (78.26056181915737, 30.79379614048742), (78.25076181915745, 30.78969614048725), (78.24396181915739, 30.786496140487372), (78.23526181915747, 30.783296140487273), (78.23076181915746, 30.78189614048722), (78.22346181915742, 30.78129614048732), (78.21266181915735, 30.78209614048729), (78.20646181915737, 30.77979614048741), (78.2034618191575, 30.7765961404873), (78.19866181915734, 30.771996140487378), (78.1982618191575, 30.76849614048735), (78.19496181915747, 30.7657961404874), (78.1941618191575, 30.76849614048735), (78.1882618191575, 30.768696140487354), (78.18196181915744, 30.76849614048735), (78.17716181915745, 30.767596140487285), (78.1705618191574, 30.766796140487372), (78.1655618191574, 30.765196140487326), (78.1571618191573, 30.761596140487317), (78.15196181915746, 30.75959614048725), (78.14906181915751, 30.762696140487215), (78.1449618191574, 30.76359614048727), (78.14086181915746, 30.763296140487288), (78.13816181915752, 30.766696140487227), (78.13466181915749, 30.768696140487354), (78.13146181915738, 30.76999614048725), (78.12666181915739, 30.772496140487362), (78.12206181915747, 30.775196140487314), (78.11796181915736, 30.77759614048728), (78.11526181915741, 30.778296140487267), (78.1120618191573, 30.77909614048741), (78.11366181915736, 30.775796140487387), (78.11616181915747, 30.77089614048731), (78.11956181915741, 30.766796140487372), (78.1216618191574, 30.764196140487346), (78.12206181915747, 30.760596140487394), (78.1222618191573, 30.757596140487294), (78.11986181915734, 30.753796140487342), (78.10956181915742, 30.744096140487272), (78.09856181915728, 30.73499614048734), (78.0910618191574, 30.72659614048741), (78.0867618191574, 30.720396140487257), (78.08396181915737, 30.714796140487355), (78.0828618191573, 30.711096140487314), (78.08126181915748, 30.713696140487283), (78.07856181915736, 30.716596140487248), (78.07536181915742, 30.719296140487362), (78.07366181915745, 30.7217961404873), (78.07096181915733, 30.725196140487412), (78.06776181915745, 30.729996140487348), (78.06386181915735, 30.733296140487372), (78.06136181915741, 30.735496140487328), (78.05796181915747, 30.738896140487274), (78.05526181915735, 30.742196140487298), (78.05156181915748, 30.745096140487252), (78.04776181915747, 30.749396140487423), (78.0451618191575, 30.751496140487234), (78.04296181915737, 30.75349614048736), (78.04036181915751, 30.755596140487402), (78.03636181915749, 30.75919614048735), (78.03486181915736, 30.763696140487358), (78.03276181915732, 30.766496140487398), (78.03016181915734, 30.77049614048741), (78.02776181915738, 30.7733961404872), (78.02516181915735, 30.77759614048728), (78.02266181915746, 30.78209614048729), (78.0192618191573, 30.7867961404873), (78.01706181915739, 30.790296140487335), (78.01516181915736, 30.792396140487376), (78.01106181915742, 30.79529614048733), (78.0072618191574, 30.796896140487373), (78.0034618191574, 30.797596140487197), (77.99986181915745, 30.79909614048734), (77.99666181915734, 30.80249614048728), (77.99416181915745, 30.806196140487376), (77.99146181915751, 30.812796140487194), (77.99096181915752, 30.816196140487303), (77.98916181915746, 30.82399614048734), (77.98846181915746, 30.8274961404872), (77.98816181915748, 30.831296140487385), (77.98656181915743, 30.83749614048736), (77.98476181915737, 30.842296140487353), (77.98466181915745, 30.845896140487305), (77.98466181915745, 30.852896140487413), (77.98386181915737, 30.859296140487405), (77.98486181915729, 30.862696140487344), (77.9843618191573, 30.869096140487333), (77.98516181915744, 30.872996140487267), (77.98586181915744, 30.876396140487206), (77.98866181915747, 30.879696140487404), (77.99156181915743, 30.88219614048734), (77.99446181915738, 30.883896140487312), (78.00446181915737, 30.885996140487293), (78.00946181915737, 30.886796140487263), (78.01196181915748, 30.888896140487304), (78.0159618191575, 30.892996140487416), (78.0159618191575, 30.896796140487254), (78.01586181915735, 30.89899614048739), (78.01346181915738, 30.90429614048731), (78.01216181915748, 30.908696140487397), (78.01176181915741, 30.912696140487416), (78.00856181915731, 30.91729614048734), (78.00436181915745, 30.921996140487348), (78.00016181915743, 30.924996140487284), (77.99526181915735, 30.928796140487236), (77.99296181915747, 30.931096140487348), (77.99036181915744, 30.932896140487404), (77.9867618191575, 30.936096140487283), (77.98506181915735, 30.93869614048731), (77.98446181915745, 30.942096140487248), (77.98466181915745, 30.94429614048739), (77.98326181915746, 30.947596140487413), (77.97936181915736, 30.949896140487283), (77.97596181915742, 30.950196140487208), (77.97236181915741, 30.950696140487192), (77.96776181915749, 30.950596140487278), (77.96436181915738, 30.950296140487353), (77.96046181915744, 30.95039614048728), (77.95586181915735, 30.950196140487208), (77.95066181915752, 30.94969614048728), (77.94546181915729, 30.949396140487295), (77.94016181915737, 30.948096140487397), (77.93406181915748, 30.94589614048727), (77.92546181915736, 30.941996140487333), (77.92026181915736, 30.938396140487384), (77.91686181915742, 30.93569614048727), (77.91336181915733, 30.93229614048733), (77.91036181915746, 30.929896140487305), (77.90596181915737, 30.927796140487324), (77.90036181915747, 30.926196140487267), (77.89326181915749, 30.924996140487284), (77.8890618191574, 30.925396140487297), (77.88546181915746, 30.926896140487266), (77.88296181915734, 30.9285961404874), (77.87966181915732, 30.931596140487276), (77.87726181915735, 30.93339614048739), (77.87466181915738, 30.93549614048721), (77.8723618191575, 30.938896140487323), (77.8680618191575, 30.94229614048726), (77.86506181915746, 30.945196140487273), (77.86316181915743, 30.94849614048724), (77.85956181915748, 30.95529614048735), (77.85616181915736, 30.963096140487323), (77.85386181915749, 30.9677961404874), (77.85236181915735, 30.971696140487325), (77.85136181915738, 30.977696140487243), (77.85026181915748, 30.98859614048729), (77.84996181915739, 30.994996140487277), (77.84926181915733, 31.001196140487256), (77.84846181915742, 31.007996140487304), (77.84626181915746, 31.017496140487317), (77.84636181915738, 31.02079614048734), (77.84596181915737, 31.025396140487263), (77.84626181915746, 31.02989614048727), (77.84626181915746, 31.03359614048737), (77.84556181915747, 31.04029614048733), (77.84476181915733, 31.045796140487255), (77.84596181915737, 31.0517961404874), (77.84546938751679, 31.055538620956156), (77.84517669242553, 31.055412360328493), (77.84517526714767, 31.055467946167376), (77.84503312325421, 31.061011558012634), (77.85036181915738, 31.061096140487333), (77.85656181915738, 31.064796140487278), (77.86386181915739, 31.079496140487276), (77.86486181915738, 31.08949614048727), (77.86586181915737, 31.094896140487307), (77.87106181915738, 31.100496140487337), (77.88666181915741, 31.107896140487316), (77.89296181915745, 31.10979614048731), (77.89296181915745, 31.117096140487327), (77.89396181915743, 31.122496140487275), (77.9032618191574, 31.133596140487274), (77.90116181915737, 31.139896140487284), (77.90636181915737, 31.142696140487285), (77.91476181915738, 31.143696140487275), (77.92206181915738, 31.140996140487285), (77.92836181915737, 31.141996140487276), (77.94716181915737, 31.153096140487285), (77.95136181915737, 31.153196140487275), (77.95336181915737, 31.156796140487273), (77.95856181915737, 31.162396140487285), (77.96796181915737, 31.164296140487277), (77.98266181915737, 31.15079614048728), (77.99936181915737, 31.15369614048728), (78.00566181915737, 31.152796140487283), (78.01926181915736, 31.143796140487275), (78.02756181915737, 31.141196140487278), (78.03066181915744, 31.1453961404873), (78.03266181915738, 31.137896140487282), (78.03166181915748, 31.14599614048723), (78.03166181915748, 31.151296140487382), (78.03066181915744, 31.1453961404873), (78.02866181915738, 31.152096140487295), (78.02856181915746, 31.15849614048733), (78.04006181915736, 31.166796140487293), (78.04316181915738, 31.17229614048728), (78.05156181915748, 31.174196140487254), (78.0661618191574, 31.17979614048733), (78.08706181915738, 31.17999614048739), (78.09226181915739, 31.178196140487334), (78.09856181915728, 31.178296140487422), (78.10586181915733, 31.181096140487284), (78.11416181915752, 31.18849614048742), (78.12046181915741, 31.191296140487285), (78.12256181915745, 31.1939961404874), (78.12566181915747, 31.194996140487323), (78.13196181915737, 31.20229614048736), (78.14656181915745, 31.20519614048737), (78.14866181915744, 31.21159614048736), (78.15756181915737, 31.2143961404874), (78.16006181915748, 31.21989614048738), (78.16736181915735, 31.21909614048741), (78.17266181915744, 31.2208961404873), (78.17786181915744, 31.220096140487392), (78.18206181915735, 31.220996140487273), (78.18726181915736, 31.219296140487305), (78.19876181915743, 31.212096140487347), (78.20396181915748, 31.21119614048729), (78.21126181915736, 31.214896140487387), (78.21436181915749, 31.223096140487257), (78.2185618191574, 31.226796140487355), (78.2237618191574, 31.227796140487325), (78.2289618191574, 31.228796140487248), (78.24256181915734, 31.2251961404873), (78.24886181915741, 31.229796140487394), (78.24886181915741, 31.234396140487327), (78.25406181915747, 31.23349614048732), (78.25926181915747, 31.237196140487356), (78.26026181915745, 31.24089614048728), (78.26346181915733, 31.243696140487316), (78.26556181915737, 31.24729614048727), (78.27286181915741, 31.255596140487285), (78.28016181915746, 31.262096140487422), (78.28846181915748, 31.25759614048741), (78.29786181915733, 31.25489614048729), (78.30416181915746, 31.25679614048727), (78.30626181915744, 31.264996140487373), (78.30626181915744, 31.275096140487285), (78.30946181915738, 31.277896140487314), (78.31566181915736, 31.276996140487256), (78.32606181915742, 31.276196140487347), (78.33656181915751, 31.278996140487383), (78.34486181915736, 31.277296140487415), (78.3573618191574, 31.28099614048728), (78.36576181915734, 31.28199614048725), (78.37826181915739, 31.279396140487226), (78.38236181915738, 31.26909614048731)]]}
```

The data I am using [can be found here](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~sandip/data.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If we examine your polygon:

```
polygon = shapefile_record['geometry']
print polygon.bounds
(77.84476181915733, 30.711096140487314, 78.59476181915738, 31.28199614048725)
```

From [Shapely manual](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html), `object.bounds`:

> Returns a (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) tuple (float values) that bounds the object.

Here minx = 77.84476181915733, miny = 30.711096140487314

= here, min longitude = 77.844... and min latitude = 30.711...

Setting your point as Point(30.9787, 78.8900) or Point(latitude, longitude), you reverse the coordinates:

```
your_point = Point(30.9787, 78.8900) # = Point(y, x)
xy_point = Point(78.8900,30.9787) # = Point(x,y)
polygon.contains(xy_point)
False
```

Which is correct:

[image]

So, the script with your example:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, shape
point = Point(78.8900,30.9787)
fc = fiona.open("AC_All_Final.shp")
print fc.schema
{'geometry': 'Polygon', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'DIST_NAME', 'str:254'), (u'Assem_No', 'int:4'), (u'AREA', 'float:18.3'), (u'PERIMETER', 'float:18.3'), (u'INDIAASSEM', 'float:11'), (u'INDIAASS', 'float:11'), (u'NO', 'float:11'), (u'ST_CODE', 'str:254'), (u'AC_NAME', 'str:254'), (u'AC_TYPE', 'str:254'), (u'PC_NO', 'float:11'), (u'AC_NO', 'float:19.11'), (u'AC_HNAME', 'str:254'), (u'PARTY', 'str:254'), (u'CODE_NO', 'str:254'), (u'Longitude', 'float:19.17'), (u'Latitude', 'float:19.17'), (u'State', 'str:50'), (u'PC_NAME', 'str:25'), (u'PC_TYPE', 'str:3'), (u'PC_CODE', 'str:10'), (u'PC_NO_1', 'int:4')])}
from feature in fc:
    if shape(feature['geometry']).contains(point):
          print feature['properties']['DIST_NAME'], feature['properties']['Longitude'], feature['properties']['Latitude']

Uttarkashi 78.8900584624 30.9787742252
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What Gene said :) Your shapefile's coordinates are in lng, lat order so you've been comparing geometries from two different coordinate systems. That won't give you the right result ever except by accident. This isn't Shapely's fault at all and a retitling of this post is in order, IMO.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. Which library did you use to plot the first map?

Comment: [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) for the two figures

Comment: Sorry :( BTW, this is pretty much the reason why GeoJSON uses longitude, latitude order in its coordinates: when you get a geographic Shapefile you'll almost always find longitude as the X and latitude as the Y.

Comment: shouldn't it be `for feature in fc:
    if shape(feature['geometry']).contains(point):`